# Error compiling CPP application. "error: 'posix_memalign' was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, cygwin

I'm trying to compile a CPP application (an open source project) in the latest cygwin64 environment using g++ 6.4.0 and I get the following error:

> error: 'posix_memalign' was not declared in this scope

now posix_memlign can be found in stdlib.h if you compile the most simple CPP "hello world" application there wouldn't be a problem calling posix_memlign.

The make file of the project report the following setup for the compilation

> g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -Wall -Wnon-virtual-dtor -I. -I./include -g -O3 -std=c++0x -g -O3 -std=c++0x -MT lib/rectangular_binary_matrix.lo -MD -MP -MF lib/.deps/rectangular_binary_matrix.Tpo -c lib/rectangular_binary_matrix.cc  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o lib/.libs/rectangular_binary_matrix.o

so it doesn't look like it override the default include path. Any ideas?

p.s.
I was able to build the code on Linux (Redhat) without a problem.

Comment: try removing `-std=c++0x` it reduces the scope of declarations

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it seems to break the build entirely much earlier on, so it is not a viable option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`posix_memalign` is not part of the C Standard Library or the C++ Standard
library and the cygwin GCC compilers do not provide it, although other
compilers may do so, including GCC compilers from other builders.

You might consider using instead the C Standard function [`aligned_alloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc), if you feel comfortable to edit your project source. It is provided in `<cstdlib>` for C++ compilation in cygwin g++ 6.4.0

**Later**

> I do see the function in C:\cygwin64\usr\include\stdlib.h...

The fact that you can find the function declaration in the header file
does not mean that the compiler can see it after preprocessing. The same
source header may be used by many builders, exposing different
declarations to the compiler depending on the builder's settings of implementor
macros. In this case, the declaration is concealed from your compiler by
the fact that `__POSIX_VISIBLE >= 200112` is false. Identifiers beginning `__` are reserved for implementors.
See the [explanation of this macro](https://github.com/Alexpux/Cygwin/blob/master/newlib/libc/include/sys/features.h)
and note the comment:

```
 * The following private macros are used throughout the headers to control
 * which symbols should be exposed.  They are for internal use only, as
 * indicated by the leading double underscore, and must never be used outside
 * of these headers.
```

Comment: I do see the function in C:\cygwin64\usr\include\stdlib.h BUT I don't see it in  C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\6.4.0\include\c++\stdlib.h

Answer (score 1):

[SOLUTION FOUND]

Hello (I'm posting this on 2 threads regarding the same problem).

I'm here because I had the "POSIX_VISIBLE >= 200112" and the "posix_memalign was not declared in this scope" issue, which was halting the compilation of a program.

I'm not a programmer and tried various fixes on my own for a couple hours. Then finally Googled & came upon this site.  The solutions here did not work for me, but I'll describe what did work:

The "posix_memalign" text was in a "stdlib.h" file that was being included into the code. The first problem was that in my "cygwin" directory, I have 25 instances of "stdlib.h"!  Which one of those was being included?! I'm all new to this, but I finally found that

echo | gcc -E -Wp,-v -

might at least give an idea of which directory the files were being "included" from. This narrowed down the number of "stdlib.h" files to 4.  Out of 4 such files, only one had the "posix_memalign" text.  I tried changing the filename of that stdlib.h to see if it would cause an error--and confirm that it was the stdlib.h in question.  However, this didn't effect the program. So I searched for a "stdlib.h" file in the next directory higher.  THAT "stdlib.h" file also had the "POSIX" text in it.  So when I changed THAT stdlib.h filename, the program DID error out.  So that was the stdlib.h to deal with.

I saw that the "POSIX_VISIBLE >= 200112" instruction effected only the ONE line of code with "posix_memalign" in it.  (In other words, the "POSIX_VISIBLE" instruction was not being used for the whole file.)  I considered "commenting" it out, or deleting it.  But then non-programmer me got the ingenious idea to simply change the ">=" to a "<".  So I now had "POSIX_VISIBLE < 200112".  I saved the file, ran the "configure" and "make" routine again, and boom, all was well. Program compiled properly.

Moral of the story, if you can determine the file (containing the POSIX statement and the posix_memalign) which is being accessed by your code, you may be able to solve your problem by just changing that one POSIX_VISIBLE operator as I did.   (And you may want to switch that operator back after your compiling is done, in case that stdlib.h library file needs to be used by other programs in the future.)